# serialize the value in <td> is possible?using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

```
var data = $("#myform").serialize();
console.log(data);

<form method="post" id="myform" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type=text name="fname"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type=text name="lname"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type=text name="age"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I was able to serialized this form using input text and using the code above my question is, Is it possible to serialize using td only if yes any idea?my form using the is like this

```
<form method="post" id="myform" action="">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td name="fname" id="fname">

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td name="lname" id="lname">

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td name="age" id="age">

    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However what is the value in this case?

Comment: the value of the td is from an input text i show all inputted data in a table, using the id. I want to use those value to be stored in database...are you sure this is feasible because the answer below says otherwise

Comment: Of course, with some custom code why not.

Comment: i see...too bad i am not yet capable of doing those kind of programming..how about anchor tag is it ok to serialize anchor that like input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to collect data yourself and then parameterize it:

```
var data = $.param($('td').map(function() {
    return {
        name: $(this).attr('name'),
        value: $(this).text().trim()
    };
}));
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var data = $.param($('td').map(function() {
    return {
        name: $(this).attr('name'),
        value: $(this).text().trim()
    };
}));

alert(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td name="fname" id="fname">First Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td name="lname" id="lname">Last Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td name="age" id="age">23</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: cool let me try it on my actual code..i'll do the upvoting afterwards

Comment: by the way how do i tell which table is being serialized because i need to tell which is which

Comment: Provide more specific selector. Like in your example if it's within form with id `myform`: `$('#myform table td').map(...)`.

Comment: `$.param($('#myform table td').map(...)` this is what i used and it returned many values.

Comment: Awesome job buddy

Answer (score 0):

No. You can not use serialization for table td.
It will work only for input controls. If you want to post td data then create your own java script object, collect td texts & post it to server.